# Subclass FileField in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I have a django model that takes an audio file:

```
class Thing(models.Model):

    audio_file = AudioFileField(    upload_to=audio_dir, blank=True, null=True )
    photo_file = models.ImageField( upload_to=img_dir,   blank=True, null=True )
    ...
```

where the `AudioFileField` is a subclass of `FileField` that performs some validation:

```
class AudioFileField(models.FileField):
    def validate(self, value, model_instance):
        try:
            if not (value.file.content_type == "audio/x-wav" or 
                    value.file.content_type == "audio/amr" or 
                    value.file.content_type == "video/3gpp"):
                raise ValidationError(u'%s is not an audio file' % value)
        except IOError:
            logger.warning("no audio file given")
```

and the `audio_dir` callback sets the path and renames the file:

```
def audio_dir(instance, filename):
        return os.path.join("audio", "recording_%s%s" % (
            datetime.datetime.now().isoformat().replace(":", "-"), 
            os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower() ))
```

In Django REST framework the `ImageField` works fine, but the subclassed `AudioFileField` doesn't. This is because the subclass `serializers.FileField` doesn't accept the keyword argument `upload_to`.

How can I expose the same functionality through the API? The `audio_dir` callback is particularly important to me.

Answer (score 0):

I search how to customize filefield and I don't know if it's fix your problem. If not I will search again for it and just tell me the error.

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    audio_file = AudioFileField(
        upload_to=audio_dir, 
        blank=True, null=True,
        content_types=['audio/x-wav', 'audio/amr', 'video/3gpp'] 
    )

    ...............

class AudioFileField(models.FileField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.content_types = kwargs.pop("content_types")

        super(AudioFileField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        data = super(AudioFileField, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

        audio_file = data.audio_file
        try:
            content_type = audio_file.content_type
            if content_type in self.content_types:
                raise ValidationError(u'{0} is not an audio file'.format(content_type))
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_('Audio file type not supported.'))
        except AttributeError:
            pass        

        return data
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a subclass of ``serializers.FileField`` that can take an ``upload_to`` parameter, or something similar. I edited the question to make it (hopefully) more clear.